# Missing Keystore from running gradlew signing Report

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradlew

I ran the command gradlew signing report on my flutter app, at the android directory folder and got the error code listed below

```
Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: release
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
```

I ran the command gradlew signing report on my flutter app, at the android directory folder and got the error code listed below

```
Task :app:signingReport
Variant: debug
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: release
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: profile
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
----------
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Tobe\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
Error: Missing keystore
```

Comment: You need to create a debug keystore in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

The error you received indicates that the debug keystore file is missing.

You can generate a new keystore and move to the correct location, after that you can rerun the signing report.

Double-check the "build.gradle" files in your project to verify that the signing configuration points to the correct keystore file and alias.

It should be in [yourprojectname]/build/android- check for missing keystore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is missing `debug.keystore`. You need to generate it.

To generate keystores for signing Android apps at the command line, use:

> $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

A debug keystore which is used to sign an Android app during development needs a specific alias and password combination as dictated by Google. To create a debug keystore, use:

> $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

- Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
- Keystore password: "android"
- Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
- Key password: "android"
- CN: "CN=Android
  Debug,O=Android,C=US"

For more details regarding signing key and keystore read [Doc for app-signing and generate-key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key)